# Triying to change hotseat position on launcher2 standalone

Tags: android, xml, edit

im making some changes to launcher2 like somepeople, well im triying to change the hotseat bar position to top instead bottom, i hide the notification bar on android manifest then i use the margin and gravity atributes on launcher.xml for moving the hotseat but only can move to the right or left not top, i hope someone can help me.

thats the code:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/dock_divider"
    layout="@layout/workspace_divider"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/button_bar_height"
    android:layout_gravity="top"/>


<include layout="@layout/hotseat"
    android:id="@+id/hotseat"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/button_bar_height_plus_padding"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"/>
```

thanks for readme!!

Comment: All the include tags are inside a FrameLayout, so you pretty much have the indepence to move them any where, but beware, your hotseat has layout_height set to 'match_parent', this is leading to fill the entire workspace and hence with a possible value of gravity or layout_gravity in hotseat layout (/layout/hotseat.xml) set to 'center' or 'center_vertical' is leading to what you might be seeing now.

Comment: try changing the layout_height in the hotseat include tag to 'wrap_content'.